# Optimizing a min/max query in Postgres on a table with hundreds of millions of rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query that is trying to find the max value of a column after grouping over two other columns:

```sql
select  address
    ,   token_id
    ,   max(input_tx_time) as last_tx_time
from processed.token_utxo
where input_tx_time < date_trunc('day', current_timestamp)
group by address, token_id
limit X
```

The table has ~330M rows and an index over all three columns ie:

```sql
create index idx_token_utxo on processed.token_utxo using btree (address, token_id, input_tx_time);
```

Running the query with a limit of 1,000,000 results in a query plan that uses the index and completes in ~1 min: https://explain.depesz.com/s/112B

However running the query with a limit of 10,000,000 results in a query plan that does not appear to use the index and completes in ~30 min: https://explain.depesz.com/s/zTkZ

If I run the query without a limit it will error out with a "temp file reached max size" so this is more than a just an issue with speed. I'm assuming the problem is the index itself is large at 20 GB (address column is a fairly long string) so it can't be loaded into memory or something like that. Would love to know what is actually going on here as well as how I can resolve this issue. Thanks in advance!

Running on PostgreSQL 13.7 with 24 GB RAM, 4 vCPU and SSD

Flags:

```
random_page_cost: 1.1
work_mem: 42598
default_statistics_target: 500
```

Comment: If address column is `a fairly long string` would it not make more sense to have an address table, with an integer id and a foreign key in token_utxo?

Comment: Yes I was thinking about doing this. It's convenient to have the address in the row. Also it introduces some non-determinism with respect to the integer id. This table is created via an idempotent airflow pipeline and by normalizing the table the integer id could be different for an address across runs of the pipeline which is not ideal

Comment: `input_tx_time` should be listed as the first column in your index

Comment: @adjuric do you need the columns in this specific order? putting `input_tx_time` in front of the other columns would do the trick: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=a32805e04501b303592806c6e747026e

Comment: "temp file reached max size" does not look like a message PostgreSQL can produce.  What is the exact error message?

Comment: I wouldn't expect the no-LIMIT plan to need any more space than the high-LIMIT plan.  Can you show the EXPLAIN, without ANALYZE of course, for the no LIMIT plan?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Changing the index to your recommendation did not change any of the query plans. To me it doesn't make sense why that should work anyway. We are aggregating by address and token_id first and then finding the max per group

Comment: @jjanes The actual message is: Error: "temporary file size exceeds temp_file_limit" and yes the no limit plan needs so much space it errors with this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by using PL/pgSQL to iteratively process chunks of the table and update the max input_tx_time after each chunk. This seems like a really good way to process large tables and it might help others. For example:

```sql
create or replace function processed.token_x_address_update_last_tx_time_fn(max_token_utxo_id bigint) returns void as
$$
declare
  token_utxo_id bigint;
begin
  -- Loop through all token_utxos 1 million at a time
  for token_utxo_id in 0..max_token_utxo_id by 1e6
  loop
    update processed.token_x_address_checkpoint as c
    set last_tx_time=u.last_tx_time
    from (
      select  address
          ,   token_id
          ,   max(input_tx_time) as last_tx_time
      from processed.token_utxo
      where token_utxo.id > token_utxo_id and token_utxo.id <= token_utxo_id
      group by address, token_id
    ) as u
    where c.address = u.address
    and c.token_id = u.token_id
    and c.last_tx_time < u.last_tx_time
    ;
  end loop;

  -- Process remainder token_utxos
  update processed.token_x_address_checkpoint as c
  set last_tx_time=u.last_tx_time
  from (
    select  address
        ,   token_id
        ,   max(input_tx_time) as last_tx_time
    from processed.token_utxo
    where token_utxo.id > floor(max_token_utxo_id / 1e6) * 1e6 and token_utxo.id <= max_token_utxo_id
    group by address, token_id
  ) as u
  where c.address = u.address
  and c.token_id = u.token_id
  and c.last_tx_time < u.last_tx_time
  ;
end;
$$ 
language plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your faster plan is using 642,780 heap fetches to fetch 2,414,121 rows, which means about 1/4 of the table is not marked as allvisible.  If you vacuum this table more aggressively, it should make that plan actually faster, and should also make it estimated to be faster.  The latter is probably more important, as the main problem you are complaining about is plan choice, not performance of the correct plan.  Making the estimate look better means this plan is more likely to be chosen.

I'm surprised to see you had already lowered random_page_cost.  Based the plan estimates, I'd assumed it was still 4 until I went back and read more closely.  What is effective_cache_size set to?  How about temp_file_limit?